# Split multiple questions from one cell to different columns

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a script which will help me to convert a csv file  to xls. In a cell, there are multiple questions and answers. I want to transform this input to a structure that has one column per question and the answers to that question on each line

I have a file which has data similar to this

```
Number, description
1010,   question1?working on customers remotely, question2? - There will be solution provided question3? Yes, question4? In UAT, question5? Me,
1011,   [question1?]working, [question2?] - There will be solution provided ,[question3?] Yes, [question4?] In UAT, [question5?] Me ,[question6?] (if yes please provide the details), [question7?] Happy
```

The output should be

```
Number, question1,  question2,  question3,  question4,  question5,  question6,  question7
1010,   working on customers remotely,  There will be solution provided,    Yes,    In UAT, Me      
1011    ,working,   There will be solution provided,    Yes,    In UAT, Me, (if yes please provide the details)],   Happy
```

Comment: Please describe the input data and the desired output more clearly - edit your question accordingly. Please post the code you have tried so far. See [ask]

Comment: @luikas - This is really great , you have edited the questions accurately this is the question  I wanted  to ask .